# unity 3d slaves objects follow master object

Tags: 3d, unity-game-engine

I'm making a snake game like this one http://www.jeux-flash-gratuit.com/jeu-482-machaon.html (in unity 3d), and i have a problem to make the bodies follow the head of the snake.

I'm using this script : https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/#/content/10236 to make a path with the head and to make the bodies follow the path. The problem is when i have a lot of bodies (50+) the script take a lot of ressource and make the game slow down.

I would like to know if is it possible to copy the movement of the body and reproduce it with a time delay and mobile friendly.

Thanks for your answers !

Answer (score 0):

The simple way would be to make a list of vector 3's ~ Each frame(or set of frames) adding a vector 3 and deleting the last one~

```
MoveWorm (vector3 newspot){
    list.add(newspot);
    list.remove(list.count - 1);
}
```